# Can one qualify for the Young Child Tax Credit if they don't qualify for the Earned Income Tax Credit

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, california

In USA California State income tax if one knows they don't qualify for the `Earned Income Credit (EITC)` can they also deduce that they are also not eligible for the `Young Child Tax Credit (YCTC)`?

California income tax instructions don't always cut to the chase and put upfront short circuit instructions to block someone from going down the rabbit hole like the Federal instructions mostly do.

## CA 540 Booklet Instructions

**Line 75 – Earned Income Tax Credit (EITC)**

Enter your Earned Income Tax Credit from form FTB 3514, California Earned Income Tax Credit, line 20.

**Line 76 – Young Child Tax Credit (YCTC)**

Enter your Young Child Tax Credit from form FTB 3514, line 28.

### FTB FORM 3514

> If you qualify for the California EITC you may also qualify for the Young Child Tax Credit (YCTC). See instructions for additional information.
>
> https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/personal/credits/california-earned-income-tax-credit.html

Seems like they left out the other half if what conditions arise when you don't qualify for the EITC and how that relates if at all to the YCTC. Just going by logic alone you know it's a fallacy ([denying the antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent)) to say

```
if EITC --> YCTC,
if not EITC then not YCTC.
```

but that seems to be what the suggestion is at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like the answer is no, you must first qualify for the EITC to be eligible to qualify for the YCTC

> Overview
>
> If you have low income and work, you may qualify for CalEITC. This credit gives you a refund or reduces your tax owed.
>
> **If you qualify for CalEITC *and*** have a child under the age of 6, you may also qualify for the Young Child Tax Credit.
>
> https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/personal/credits/california-earned-income-tax-credit.html

There is is right there the AND in the overview. So yes if you don't qualify for the EITC you cannot claim the YCTC.